# "create temp table" em trigger no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, trigger

É possível criar uma trigger de insert em uma "Tabela1" usando "CREATE TEMP TABLE" em sua estrutura e alimentar uma "Tabela2"?

Comment: Podes actualizar a pergunta colocando mais detalhes sobre o resultado que desejas obter?

Comment: Uma trigger supõe uma ação rápida , qual seria a necessidade de se criar uma "temp" ?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem o que deseja fazer, mas você pode sim criar tabelas temporarias na sua trigger.

Ex:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_table1_tbi() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

BEGIN     

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 ON COMMIT DROP AS 
    SELECT NEW.*;

    RETURN NEW; 
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER table1_tbi BEFORE INSERT
ON table1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_table1_tbi();
```

Neste caso a tabela temporaria table2 sera deletada ao executar o commit.

Comment: E o perguntador some ...